# Display the json message from an mqtt server on my terminal (mosquitto)

Tags: python, mqtt

Hello I am trying to transfer data from a raspberry pi 2 device and receive it on the terminal of another computer through mqtt. The part were I publish my `json` information on `mosquitto` is perfectly working. The part were I subscribe is down below:

```
import time
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

broker="test.mosquitto.org"

#define callback
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    time.sleep(1)
    try:
        print("received message =", str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")))
    except None:
        print("")

client=mqtt.Client()

client.on_message = on_message
#####
print("connecting to broker ",broker)
client.connect(broker)

client.loop_start() #start loop to process received messages

print("subscribing ")
client.subscribe("DHT22_cimti_project_pe") #subscribe

client.loop_forever()
```

The problem is, when I run this on my MacBooks Terminal, it is working but it always eventually crash with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mqtt2.py", line 26, in <module>
    client.loop_forever()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py",    line 1481, in loop_forever
    rc = self.loop(timeout, max_packets)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1003, in loop
    rc = self.loop_read(max_packets)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1284, in loop_read
    rc = self._packet_read()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1849, in _packet_read
    rc = self._packet_handle()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2305, in _packet_handle
    return self._handle_publish()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2464, in _handle_publish
    (slen, packet) = struct.unpack(pack_format, self._in_packet['packet'])
struct.error: bad char in struct format
```

I tried to do a `try` `except` method but it did not work so I decided to go on a windows computer. But there it's even worst because the program is not even giving me the data that I am sending to the mqtt server. I directly receive the following error:

```
[WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.
```

So my question is. Why on windows do I get this error when on mac it is working (even though it crashes) and how can I solve this problem (on windows and why not on mac if possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you are trying to start the network loop twice, which will never work.

Next you should really be waiting for confirmation of connection before subscribing so adding an `on_connect` callback is a good idea.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

broker="test.mosquitto.org"

#define callback
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
  try:
    print("received message =", str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")))
  except None:
    print("")

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
  print("Connection returned result: "+connack_string(rc))
  print("subscribing ")
  client.subscribe("DHT22_cimti_project_pe") #subscribe

client=mqtt.Client()

client.on_message = on_message
client.on_connect = on_connect

#####
print("connecting to broker ",broker)
client.connect(broker)

client.loop_forever() #start loop to process received messages
```

Lastly really you should not be blocking in the `on_message` callback so remove the `time.sleep(1)`

Comment: Thank You so much now it's working without any crashes ^^

Comment: what about if i have many callbacks and each one is handled by thread so i need to call the loop_forever many times in the same process which lead to the same error

Comment: No, there is only ever 1 client thread, calling `loop_forever()` on multiple threads will not magically get you multithreaded message handling.